# Is the Closest Pair of Points Algorithm always accurate?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, divide-and-conquer

Using divide and conquer, Is the Closest Pair of Points Algorithm always accurate? If not,then when is it not
Accurate or when can I not apply it? Like for instance I have this algorithm:

```
CLOSEST-PAIR (p1, p2, …, pn)

Compute separation line L such that  half the points are on each side of the line.
 δ1 ← CLOSEST-PAIR (points in left half).
 δ2 ← CLOSEST-PAIR (points in right half).
 δ ← min { δ1 , δ2 }.
 Delete all points further than δ from line L.
 Sort remaining points by y-coordinate.
 Scan points in y-order 
 and compare  distance between each point
 and next 11 neighbors. 
 If any of these distances is less than δ,      update δ.
  RETURN δ
```

I can't find a scenario where it isn't accurate.

Comment: Closest Pair of Points is a problem, which can be solved by various different algorithms; can you provide the specific algorithm?

Comment: The divide and conquer algorithm

Comment: When all calculations are exact, the algorithm is accurate. With floating point numbers, who knows.

Comment: BTW 11 points are not needed, 7 are enough.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Okay. Thank you